# Broken BIOS + grub rescue

Tags: windows-10, bios, grub

Long story short: I installed MXLinux alongside Windows but later uninstalled it by formatting the Linux partitions from the Disk Management utility in Windows.

I rebooted the computer and I'm stuck on the grub rescue terminal.

I know I need Windows to install the Windows boot loader again and for that I need the USB utility they provide. I downloaded it and burned it to a USB stick but my computer won't boot from it. It goes straight to the grub rescue terminal.

I know I need to change the boot order in the BIOS but the problem is: since I installed MXLinux, I can't access my BIOS. It just shows an underscore in the top left corner.

I've read from other threads that I can open my PC and reset the CMOS. I don't want to open my computer since I don't even know what a CMOS is and I'm afraid to ruin something.

Is there anything that I can do from the grub rescue menu?

`ls`:

```
(hd0),(hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

`set`:

```
cmdpath=(hdo0,gpt1)/EFI/MX19
prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt5
```

I tried:

```
set boot=(hd0,gpt5)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub
```

but when I run `insmod normal`
I get

```
error: no such partition
```

I also saw somewhere that I could do `fwsetup` but that command was not recognized.

I'm quite lost. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've entered the BIOS many times before so I know the key to enter it in this PC (F2). But when I do it, it always shows me the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

With [the help of the MXLInux forum](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=104&p=605965&sid=20954ef382e89bb12325a58a88be06ae#p605965), I ended up solving it by using a Live USB MXLInux stick.

When it booted from it, I chose "boot rescue menu" and then "Find Windows bootladers" and I booted from the one it found.

That brought me into Windows, where I used msconfig to restore the boot options to default.

This made the Windows boot loader the default AND fixed my BIOS.